# Python to load and execute its code in memory

Tags: python-2.7, ram

I was wondering if it is possible for a python script to run in ram. Possiably some sort library that allows this. Once the code is stored in memory I want to run the program like is is on the hard drive.

Comment: I'd say it always runs in RAM, after having loaded the module from disk. Can you explain what you mean? What would it look like?

Comment: In other words I want to load a python program into RAM and delete the script from the hard drive. Then execute that program from memory.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the program finishes? Do you want to ever call it again? Where should it be in memory in the meantime? Why do you want to remove the program from disk?

Comment: When the program finishes is will be done, nothing else will happen. Im simply wondering if it is possible to run a python program in ram without the hard drive

Comment: @MatthewLukaszewski have you found a solution? If yes please write it here! Thank you!